# How can i switch to a different project / repo in git

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a project called e-Portal and a project called event-Reg. I changed directory to my event-Reg project and typed `git status` but it says I am still on on a branch that belongs to e-Portal. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Changing a branch requires you to check out the branch. (`git checkout branchname`).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to switch branches without committing. There is a good how-to from gitguys [in this link](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/switching-branches-without-committing/). They explain how to switch with and without conflict.

Answer (score -1):

you should checkout to the other project. Please try this: 
git checkout event-Reg